# Train Test Split sklearn based on group variable

Tags: python, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas, train-test-split

My X is as follows:
EDIT1:

```
Unique ID.   Exp start date.   Value.    Status.
001          01/01/2020.       4000.     Closed
001          12/01/2019        4000.     Archived
002          01/01/2020.       5000.     Closed
002          12/01/2019        5000.     Archived
```

I want to make sure that none of the unique IDs that were in training are included in testing. I am using sklearn test train split. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

I believe you need `GroupShuffleSplit` ([documentation here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GroupShuffleSplit.html)).

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import GroupShuffleSplit
X = np.ones(shape=(8, 2))
y = np.ones(shape=(8, 1))
groups = np.array([1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3])
print(groups.shape)

gss = GroupShuffleSplit(n_splits=2, train_size=.7, random_state=42)

for train_idx, test_idx in gss.split(X, y, groups):
    print("TRAIN:", train_idx, "TEST:", test_idx)

TRAIN: [2 3 4 5 6 7] TEST: [0 1]
TRAIN: [0 1 5 6 7] TEST: [2 3 4]
```

It can be seen from above that train/test indices are created based on the `groups` variable.

In your case, `Unique ID.` should be used as groups.

Comment: Is there a way to make sure this split is also stratified?

Comment: using `GroupShuffleSplit`? No. You need to code that.

Comment: I just found sklearn's implementation of [groupstratifiedkfold](https://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedGroupKFold.html) but I can't seem to get it running on my system due to an ImportError. Could you help me with that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68226119/14022582)?