# ImportError: cannot import name 'StratifiedGroupKFold' from 'sklearn.model_selection'

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm getting an ImportError when I try to use the [`StratifiedGroupKFold`](https://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedGroupKFold.html#sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedGroupKFold) split from `sklearn`.

I noticed to use it the nightly build is required and I've installed it, yet I get the error. Any suggestions on how to solve this are welcome.

**Edit**: I tried updating conda and then scikit learn and even then it did not work. On installing the night build, it says requirements already satisfied.

Do I need to uninstall scikit-learn and then install the nightly build? Am I missing something here?

**Edit 2:** I created a new virtual environment and installed the nightly build in the same. Here, the `import` works fine on the terminal and Spyder but for some strange reason it does not work on jupyter-notebook (which is also installed in the same virtual environment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than trying to install nightly version, I would go for installing from the source. See instructions [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/advanced_installation.html#building-from-source)

BTW, I don't see any issues for me, when importing `StratifiedGroupKFold` from the dev version

```
[ins] In [2]: import sklearn                                                                                                                                           
sklearn.__version__

[ins] In [3]: sklearn.__version__                                                                                                                                      
Out[3]: '1.0.dev0'

[ins] In [4]: import numpy as np 
         ...: from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedGroupKFold                                                                                                 

[ins] In [5]:
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I will try building from source. When I use the dev version, I'm able to import it on the terminal, but it does not work in jupyter-notebook (which has been installed in the same virtual environment)

Answer (score 0):

I got this error message when trying to use the [FLAML](https://github.com/microsoft/FLAML) library. Hence, sharing my solution in case anyone got this error when trying to import flaml library.

1. !pip install --upgrade pip
2. !pip install scikit-learn
3. !pip install flaml

After this three installations, I was able to get rid of this error when trying to import flaml.